# Existence of diagonal modes in particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

This idea has been confusing me ever since we studied periodic boundary conditions in solid state physics. Why don't we incorporate diagonal modes in our analysis of wavefunctions with periodic boundary conditions. By diagonal modes I mean, say in 3d, a wavefunction running from one edge of a cube to the other ($\sqrt3$ long). I mean, they should satisfy our boundary conditions (i.e going to zero outside of the 3d infinite well). Does this have something to do with the symmetry of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by a diagonal mode wavefunction. The ansatz
\begin{equation}
\psi_1(x, y, z) = C_1 \sin \left [ \frac{\pi}{L} \left ( \frac{L}{2} + x - y \right ) \right ] \sin \left [ \frac{\pi}{L} \left ( \frac{L}{2} + y - z \right ) \right ] \sin \left [ \frac{\pi}{L} \left ( \frac{L}{2} + z - x \right ) \right ]
\end{equation}
obtains a maximum along the main diagonal $x = y = z$ but it does not obey the boundary conditions. For instance, plug in $x = 0$ and there are plenty of points $(y, z) \in [0, L]^2$ for which $\psi_1(0, y, z) \neq 0$.

But anyway, the answer is that using separation of variables on the Schroedinger equation (which we can do because of symmetry) tells us all the energy eigenstates so any other solution you can think of must be a linear combination of them. One thing you can do is multiply $\psi_1(x,y,z)$ by the ground state to get
\begin{equation}
\psi_2(x,y,z) = C_2 \sin \left ( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ) \sin \left ( \frac{\pi y}{L} \right ) \sin \left ( \frac{\pi z}{L} \right ) \psi_1(x, y, z)
\end{equation}
which has some "preference" for the main diagonal. This is normalizable and obeys the boundary conditions of the box so it must be a solution. It will just evolve in a non-trivial way according to the usual rule where you give each eigenstate in its decomposition a different phase.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you so much. I tried drawing what I had thought of on a paper for the 2d case and realized I had asked something of a non-question. In my head I was visualizing the wave function in 2d still as a sine wave in 1d. But the idea that you can come up with wavefunctions that have a "preference" for the diagonal as you said is actually very interesting!